# Permisos para proyecto desplegado en Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, permisos, war

Tengo una aplicación desplegada en Tomcat(Backend) la cual se conecta a otro servidor donde tengo montado Apache (Frontend), en dicha aplicación hay un modulo que permite subir archivos pdf, al momento de guardar el archivo me arroja el mensaje de "error al crear al directorio para los documentos."

Visualizando el log de catalina.out, ofrece el mismo comentario que "error al crear al directorio para los documentos.", probé cambiando los permisos del directorio del proyecto dentro de webapps usando el 750-777(Se que este ultimo no se debe dar, lo hice como prueba.) para permitir a tomcat crear la carpeta.

De igual forma al archivo .war he cambiado los permisos antes de moverlo al directorio webapps esto con el fin de que el usuario y el grupo pueddan escribir, leer y ejecutar

[image: Permisos del war antes]

Solo que el cambiar los permisos se ilumina de verde y al final tiene un *
[image: War despues de los permisos y cambio de usuario]

También he intentado crear la ruta asignando los permisos y usuarios, pero aun asi el mensaje es el mismo.

¿Saben que puede estar pasando?

Utilizo apache Tomcat 9-0-45 y en los servidores tengo Ubuntu server 20.4.

Comment: Pero ¿en cuál directorio se quiere crear el subdirectorio?

Comment: Al ser un proyecto hecho en intellij, la carpeta tendría que estar en src/main/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolverlo, al crear sobre el directorio raíz la carpeta contenedora y después cambiando el propietario de la carpeta y sus permisos de la siguiente forma:

mkdir src
sudo chown tomcat:tomcat src/
sudo chmod -R 750 src/